# Windows 11 search apps behaviour

Tags: windows-11, windows-search

I'm quite frustrated by the behaviour of Windows 11 search, and I wish to understand if this is expected:

I have installed Libreoffice suite, which includes "LibreOffice Calc" app. It's found (among the others apps) as I type "Libreo" in the search box... as expected.

[image]

However, if I type "Cal" or "Calc" alone, it is not shown.

[image]

[image]

Perhaps the search is not a simple partial match, it only matches the string that begins with "Cal" ?

That would be strange, and it does not seems to be the case. If I type "Chro", the "Google Chrome" app is shown.

[image]

So what is happening here? Am I missing something?

Comment: Make sure your USERS folder is indexed.  Otherwise I would expect full matches to show up first. So calc show calculator.  That is normal behavior.

Comment: When I said “fulll”  calc finds Calculator as that starts with calc .  Libre Office Calc does not start with calc . This is how I see windows search work and this is normal

Comment: "This is how I see windows search work and this is normal "
I don't think so. If I type "Code" if finds "Vs Code" , I type "Tool" (or even "ool") and it finds "Snipping tool"

Comment: So as I noted search depends on both what is indexed as well as the search term.  Overall it appears to be working as designed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good Microsoft Article on Windows Search

[Windows Search](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/a-guide-to-using-windows-search-two-alternatives/b0f4229d-623a-46dd-a84e-94e666bbe505)

From the article and that speaks directly to your post:

> Windows only looks for the search terms at the start of words.  It
> will not find the search term if it only appears later in a word.  For
> example, if you enter bert in the search box then it will find Bert &
> Bertie but not Albert or Ethelbert.  However, if you enter *bert in
> the search box then it will find Bert, Bertie, Albert & Ethelbert.

=======

So when you enter calc  it finds calculator and not LibrOffice Calc .

However if you enter *calc , then it should find LibreOffice Calc.

I tested this on my Windows 11 machine, searched for *commander and found the App Total Commander. *comm finds both Command and Lenovo Commercial Vantage

So what you see is normal and as designed, and, additionally, changing the search term judiciously will normally find what you want.

For my very common Apps, I put them on my Desktop to be 100 percent accurate.

Comment: "However if you enter *calc , then it should find LibreOffice Calc" It doesn't. 
I also have Total Commander, and it's found with or without the *

Comment: I don't have LibreOffice  but I added another test.  So it may also depend on if your index includes LibreOffice.   Overall I think you search is working about the same as mine and so normal

Answer (score 0):

I understand that your problem is with the Windows Start menu,
whose behavior (and bugs) changes with each new Windows release,
which is quite frustrating.

My first action with a new computer is to replace it by a free
third-party utility which has better performance and more options
and is more reliable.

My favorite is
[Open-Shell-Menu](https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu),
but there are other
[alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/classic-start/).